# CMD command with more lines

Tags: cmd

I need to make 4 steps in the cmd
something like

1. Change to directory
2. Enter ..... -> Then an programm opens
   This programm needs to parameters:
   First enter spw (set password) Enter
   Second enter password.

I can combine the steps 1 and 2 with cd .... & command

I tried to enter the next two steps with an input file but it does not work.

> So my input file looks like that:
>
> spw
>
> Password

But it does not work.

So here is my question is there some method to run these 4 steps in one command line? (I can only enter one command, than the next command will start from scratch)

Please help me out on that.

Thanks and Regards,

Eros Kilinc

Comment: `Then an programm opens`, is this a GUI program or text-based ?

Comment: What is about redirection ? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: this is what i meant with an input file
my full command looked like : cd   & command >C:\input.txt 
but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

You tried `command >C:\input.txt`. That will put the output from `command` into `input.txt`.

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to send the content of `input.txt` to your command. To do this, write:

`command <C:\input.txt`

(`<` instead of `>`)